# Error while upgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core

I am trying to upgrade version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to 2.1.1. After upgrading to 2.1.1 I am getting error shown in screenshot on following code of piece marked in bold

```
var queryCompiler = (IQueryCompiler)_queryCompilerField.GetValue(queryable.Provider);
var queryModelGenerator = (**IQueryModelGenerator**)_queryModelGeneratorField.GetValue(queryCompiler);
var queryModel = queryModelGenerator.ParseQuery(queryable.Expression);
var database = _databaseField.GetValue(queryCompiler);
var queryCompilationContextFactory = ((DatabaseDependencies)_dependenciesProperty.GetValue(database)).QueryCompilationContextFactory;
var queryCompilationContext = queryCompilationContextFactory.Create(false);
var modelVisitor = (**RelationalQueryModelVisitor**)queryCompilationContext.**CreateQueryModelVisitor**();
modelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor<TEntity>(queryModel);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code here for better understanding!

Comment: If the answer below not works for you, you can share your project(without any sensitive info) , and then we can help you to check the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Error while upgrading **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** version:

Usually, the type or namespace could not be found error occurs if you are referencing a namespace that is not found by the compiler. It means that when upgrading to later version, the referenced assembly is not installed or if the namespace or type changed in a newer version.

***Need to check & resolve:-***

- Uninstall the package and reinstall it. Rebuilding the solution will sometimes work because it clears all the cache and rebuilds it.
- Reload your project in solution explorer (VScode) and modify the .csproj if any package reference exists.
- To avoid these errors, change your package reference to **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All**. All Entity Framework references will be included.

[image]

- If the namespace has changed in the version which you are trying to upgrade, you must update your code requirements accordingly.
- Check whether you are correctly referencing the installed version in code.

**Note**: Any other packages that rely on **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** must be compatible with **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** version.

Check dependencies [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/2.1.1#dependencies-body-tab).

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.1).